# Writing to a worksheet using vba excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to programming so please forgive me if this problem is easy.

I am writing data obtained from a userform to a worksheet. Row 1 is used fir headings so the data would be entered at row2 if row 2 is used I would like to write to the following row.

Just now I have code that finds the next empty row on the worksheet. I have headings half way down the worksheet to display something separate but because of the search cell code I am using it writes the data that should be at the top of the worksheet under the headings I have half way down the page.

I am just looking to start writing at A2 then onto the next row.

Cheers in advance for your help.

Craig

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what I think you are trying to do then there are a couple of ways you can do this.
You can loop through the cells which has it's uses but is considered inefficient :

```
Range("A2").Select

Do
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

ActiveCell.Value = "YourValue"
```

The most efficient way would probably be to use the xlDown command:

```
Range("A2").Select

ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Different Way"
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for the vote down. Thanks.